# AWS Elasticsearch : URL encoding for search across multiple indices and types

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elastic-map-reduce

I am using AWS elasticsearch and using AWS signature V4 to communicate with the instance.
Simple queries to create/search indexes are working fine.
But I want to have a functionality where I should be able to search across multiple indices and multiple types.
So my URL becomes :
http://my_aws_es_instance/index1,index2/type1,type2

Since its a AWS elasticsearch instance  I formed canonical request like below:
Please note I have url encoded the URI.

POST
/index1%2Cindex2/type1%2Ctype2/_search

content-type:application/json
host:my_aws_es_instance
x-amz-date:date

content-type;host;x-amz-date
hash value of my paylod

However AWS double encodes the "%" sign and expects following format and give 403 Forbidden error with following cannonical request.

POST
/index1%252Cindex2/type1%252Ctype2/_search

content-type:application/json
host:my_aws_es_instance
x-amz-date:date

content-type;host;x-amz-date
hash value of my paylod

Answer (score 0):

The same question is [Elasticsearch to query across multiple indices and multiple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633177/elasticsearch-to-query-across-multiple-indices-and-multiple-types)

and ans is to create only request with encoded uri