# Elasticsearch to query across multiple indices and multiple types

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-map-reduce, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am newbie to elasticsearch .I am using AWS elastic search instance 5.1.1.
I have a requirement where I need to specify multiple indices and types in request body of Elasticsearch for search operation ,is it possible ? What is the simplest way to do it an example would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Referring back to [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-index-multi-type.html)  you can try doing a simple CURL as below

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty'
```

This should ideally query across all indices and types.

Hope This helps!

Comment: Thanks segFaulter,Christian
But it would be more efficient if we can search across specific indices and types.
Also I want to avoid the pattern:
/gb,us/user,tweet/_search
So is there any other way we can specify multiple indices and types ?

Answer (score 0):

When creating Canonical Request you need to URI encode with escape character like

```
>  str.replaceAll("%20", " "))).toString()
>                 .replaceAll("%3A", ":")
>                 .replaceAll("%2F", "/")
>                 .replaceAll("%3B", ";")
>                 .replaceAll("%40", "@")
>                 .replaceAll("%3C", "<")
>                 .replaceAll("%3E", ">")
>                 .replaceAll("%3D", "=")
>                 .replaceAll("%26", "&")
>                 .replaceAll("%25", "%")
>                 .replaceAll("%24", "$")
>                 .replaceAll("%23", "#")
>                 .replaceAll("%2B", "+")
>                 .replaceAll("%2C", ",")
>                 .replaceAll("%3F", "?");
```